# Stack Overflow View - Visual Studio code extension

Tags: app, search, dev-tool

#### About:

This is a Visual Studio Code extension that allows developers to search Stack Overflow inside of the text editor, to quickly access answers and view questions.

#### Screenshot / Code Snippet:

[image]

#### Download / Install:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=4tron.stack-overflow-view

#### Platform:

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com)

#### License:

[MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

#### Code:

This was built mainly with [svelte](https://svelte.dev)

https://github.com/IsaacSomething/stackoverflow-view-vscode